# How can I validate data from scanner (Java)

Tags: java, validation, java.util.scanner

I need to ask the user to input a number from 1 to 10 then get the factorial of this number, I was able to do everything except to validation of the user name ( To be within range && not a string)

```
package test2;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int userInput = 0 ;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter a number from 2 to 100");

        if (sc.nextInt() < 101) {
            userInput = sc.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.println(userInput);

    }

}
```

Comment: You don't ask for the *user name* so I guess you talked about the *user input*. Basically, you want to ask the user to enter some input until a valid one is found?

Comment: What user name are you talking about exactly? Is the number from 1 to 10 (or 2 to 100 according to your code) supposed to be the user name?

Comment: Your question is not descriptive enough. You are sayign you can do everything except validation of user name. Where is the user name you need to ask user for ? is it variable userInput ?

Answer (score -1):

```
    int userInput = 0;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter a number from 2 to 100");
    while (!sc.hasNextInt()) {
        System.out.println("Please enter number");
        sc.next();
    }
    while(true) {
        userInput = sc.nextInt();
        if (userInput > 2 && userInput < 100) {
            break;
        }else{
            System.out.println("Please enter a number between 2 to 100");
        }
    }
    System.out.println(userInput);
```

Comment: What if user enters `"yohoho"`?

Comment: This doesn't check the input type.

Comment: I have updated my answer check it now

Answer (score -1):

Or simply use a do-while

```
 do {

   userInput = sc.nextInt();

 } while (userInput < 1 || userInput > 10);
```

Answer (score -1):

one Method you can try is

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

int userInput = 0 ;
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Please enter a number from 2 to 100");

while (!sc.hasNextInt())
{
 System.out.println("wrong input");
 sc.next();
}  

if (sc.nextInt() < 101) {
    userInput = sc.nextInt();
}
System.out.println(userInput);

 }
}
```